# How to control Android Chromium's text selection handles on JavaScript level?

Tags: javascript, android, chromium

In an Android application, I use an WebView to load an html page with texts.

When long click on texts, the blue Chromium text selection handles show up so that I could drag to change the text selection and do actions like cut/copy/paste.

But the blue handles are on the Chromium level. Is it possible to control those blue handles on JavaScript level (or on Android level)?

For example, when some DOM events fired (or Android events), I want to move the right-side blue handles to the next line's 3rd character.

I've seen workaround to intercept the native Chromium selection and create customized selection handles, e.g. https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection, but here I'm wondering if I could directly get control over the Chromium's text selection handles via some Chromium's public API either open to JavaScript or Android?